# How add options to a select with an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select tag (to be used for country selection) which I want to prefill with options using a directive:

```
<select class="countryselect" required ng-model="cust.country"></select>
```

My directive goes like

```
return {
  restrict : "C",
  link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
     var countries = [
        ["AND","AD - Andorra","AD"],
        ["UAE","AE - Vereinigte Arabische Emirate","AE"]
        ... //loop array and generate opt elements
        iElement.context.appendChild(opt);
    }
  }
```

I am able to fill the select with additional options, but the ng-model binding does not work. Even if cust.country has a value (e.g. "UAE"), the option is not selected.

How to make the select display the value of cust.country? If think I have some timing problem here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use directive from Angular JS:

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="c.name for c in countries"></select>
{{country}}
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
   $scope.countries = [
    {name:'Vereinigte Arabische Emirate', value:'AE'},
    {name:'Andorra', value:'AD'},
  ];

  $scope.country = $scope.countries[1]; 

});
```

Check the docs of select: [Angular Select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)

**EDIT WITH DIRECTIVE**

**Directive:**

```
  app.directive('sel', function () {
    return {
        template: '<select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="c.name for c in countries"></select>',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            selectedValue: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.countries = [{
                name: 'Vereinigte Arabische Emirate',
                value: 'AE'
            }, {
                name: 'Andorra',
                value: 'AD'
            }, ];
            scope.selectedValue = scope.countries[1];
        }
    };
});
```

**Main controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.country={};

})
```

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<sel selected-value="country"></sel>
{{country}}
</div>
```

Working Example: [EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/V5ub3CBRMlQcjGMs2Px2)

Comment: I agree that for a single country-select field this is the perfect solution. In my case I have several county-select fields, so I want to make it more reuseable.

Comment: Please check my edit. Now you have all in directive and can easy bind to other varibles.

Comment: I would also suggest using `replace: true` here as it would remove the wrapping `<sel>` element from the final HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the options to the ngModelController so that this works. E.g. like this:

```
return {
    restrict : 'C',
    require: ['select', 'ngModel'],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        var countries = [['A', 'text text']];
        countries.forEach(option => {
            const optionElement = angular.element('<option/>')
                .attr('value', option[0])
                .text(option[1]);

            element.append(optionElement);
            controllers[0].addOption(option.value, optionElement);
        });
    }
};
```